# The standard method for adding css classes to twig templates

Tags: theming, 8

What is the standard method for adding classes in twig template?
I'm going straightly to the main subject point:

**Scenario-1:**
I have some classes and I want to collect them in a group and add this group to the existing group that added before:
I try below code but it seems that something is wrong.

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'block',
    'block-' ~ configuration.provider|clean_class,
    'block-' ~ plugin_id|clean_class,
  ]
%}

{%
  set my-classes = [
    'class-name-1',
    'class-name-2',
    'class-name-3',
    'class-name-4',
  ]
%}
<div{{ attributes.addClass('classes my-classes') }}>
```

What tips should I consider for a class group name, For example, Is it important to follow `PHP` variables name convention, Can I use hyphen character in class group names?

**Scenario -2:**
I have few classes names and I want to add theme straightly to default added classes, like below:

`views-view-unformatted:`

```
<div {{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes 'class-name-1 class-name-2') }}>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variables `classes`and `my_classes` are arrays. You could merge them:

```
{{ attributes.addClass(classes, my_classes) }}
```

Or add them one by one:

```
{{ attributes.addClass(classes).addClass(my_classes) }}
```

Or merge an array constant directly:

```
{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes, ['class-name-1', 'class-name-2']) }}
```

Or single classes:

```
{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes, 'class-name-1', 'class-name-2') }}
```

According to the coding standards https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/coding_standards.html you should use underscores in variable names.

Comment: Thank you so much, for your help and reply. I appreciate you greatly.